# 2 queries on loading webpage blocking each other

Tags: database, web-applications

I am making a webpage which on load makes 2 queries. However, results of both queries are coming at same time (the longer time) because one is blocking the other. Is there a way i can give a time delay so the other query is made only after the data from first query is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Although the information you are providing are not sufficient, I am assuming you are making Ajax requests using Javascript. If that is the case you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) in order to have some code that will run only after the request answer is received (it might have an error)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "URL for first request here",
  method: 'Your request method (POST, GET etc)',
  data: 'Here assign any data you need to send'
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // This code will be called only if your request is successful
    // data is the response from the server
    // Perform 2nd Request
    $.ajax({
      url: "URL for second request here",
      method: 'Your request method (POST, GET etc)',
      data: 'Here assign any data you need to send'
    })
    .done(function( data ) {

    })
    .fail(function(){

    });
})
.fail(function(){
    // This code will be called only if your request fails
});
```